# Typesetting a descending italic z

Tags: fonts, kpfonts

I have a document which has many short quotes in which I would like to imitate the fonts. For this document I am limited to `LaTeX` (not `LuaTeX`) by the publisher. The `jkpvos` font family from `kpfonts` does a reasonable job with this Marin Mersenne (1625) except for the descending z (4th and 5th line below). How might I imitate it with `LaTeX`?

[image: Font example to be reproduced with LaTeX]

Added to original question: It does not need to be perfect.  The image below is what I have for this quote, and it is sufficient for my purposes (other than the z).

[image]

Comment: Do you know if the 'z' you're looking for is included in `kpfonts`? Also, could you add a little code sample showing what you're doing so far to approach the sample?

Comment: Take a look at [the Fell types](http://iginomarini.com/fell/the-revival-fonts/). They are easy to use with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet I'm assuming if he says he has to use LaTeX and can't use LuaLaTeX, then XeLaTeX won't be an option either, unfortunately.

Comment: @doncherry: probably, yes, but the fonts are also available as TTF, so they can be used with pdflatex if need be.

Comment: Couldn't the publisher take PDF?

Comment: They explicitly say "no pdf" (and yes doncherry, no XeLaTeX either)

Comment: @doncherry It looks like the Chris just loaded `kpfonts` with `nofligatures` and `veryoldstyle` options. The manual for `kpfonts` does not mention a descending `z`, yet mentions a toggle for a long tail on `Q`. So I expect that the `z` Chris is looking for is not in `kpfonts`.

Comment: Is it your main text, or just a quote in the text?

Comment: Just one of a hundred+ quotes in six languages, multiple fonts, ....

Comment: If the publisher says "no pdf", what format are you submitting in?

Comment: `LaTeX` (not `LuaTeX` ...).

Comment: And could you use your own font? There're ways how to transfer a font such way that LaTeX understand it.

Comment: (given you are desperate enough) you could create the character yourself using METAFONT and ship the fontfile with you texsource (although that might require the publisher to set $TFMFONTS or friends)

Comment: Note that while the "long s" is an orthographic necessity, the "z" is a mere artistic feature of the font.  So in my humble opinion, you do already an authentic job by keeping orthography.

Answer (score 1):

Try Dominican Italic font at

http://www.fontparadise.com/fonts.php?SearchFor=dominican&type=search

I believe it is a free download

There is also Garamond MT Italic at

http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Garamond+MT+Italic/

Comment: They seem to have the "z with my-hand-was-sore-when-drawing-the-last-line", however, the examples show the modern "s". whereas the OP seems to want the "long s".

Comment: @tohecz I had the impression that the questioner wasn't looking for a complete font replacement for the whole alphabet, but was in some way just going to use the hand-was-sore-"z".  Of course, mixing characters from fonts would generally stick out like a sore thumb.  As far as antique "s" characters, many fonts will have both forms of s (the antique as a special character or alternate font set), since even in antique penmenship, both forms of s were used, depending on the context (antique s mid-word, modern s at word end).