# Use african font with TeX Live 2013/Debian

Tags: packages, texlive

How can I make `fc` package work with TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) on ubuntu ? In fact I want to use African fonts and I found [this document](http://www.clemson.edu/economics/faculty/wilson/latex/doc/comprehensive-latex-symbol-list.pdf). Can somebody tell me how to install this `fc` package or its dependencies ?

Comment: The readme file for the package at http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/fonts/jknappen/fc/src/fc.rme might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried it like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T4]{fontenc} % loading the fc package

\begin{document}
    \B{D}\B{d}\B{H}\B{h}\B{t}\B{T}%
    \m{b}\m{V}\m{C}\m{c}\m{D}%
    \M{d}\M{D}%
    \m{d}\m{E}\m{e}%
    \M{E}\M{e}%
    \m{f}\m{F}\m{G}\m{g}\m{I}\m{i}\m{J}\m{j}\m{K}\m{k}\m{N}\m{n}\m{o}\m{O}\m{P}\m{p}\m{s}\m{S}%
    \M{t}\M{T}%
    \m{t}\m{T}\m{u}\m{U}\m{Y}\m{y}\m{z}\m{Z}%
    \T{E}\T{e}\T{O}\T{o}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

When zooming in, you will notice a quite bad quality of the letters (they are not scalable). So you might want to search the letters you need on http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html and use them like this:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for \DJ\DH\dj
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tipa} % for \textcrh

\begin{document}
 \DH\DJ\dj\textcrh\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And you can always go the unicode way with some font you like:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
    \symbol{"0189}\symbol{"0111}\symbol{"0126}\symbol{"0127}\symbol{"0167}\symbol{"0166}\symbol{"0253}\symbol{"0181}\symbol{"0187}\symbol{"0188}\dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Right, seem to work. But I'm using `garamondx` font. I'm getting errors like `! LaTeX Error: Command \m unavailable in encoding T1.` though I don't mention `T1` in `fontenc` options. What's wrong ?

Comment: @sk001 From the `garamondx` doc: "The package uses T1 encoding—this is built into the package and need not be specified separately." The symbols in my first example use the T4 encoding. I do not know, if `garamondx` does support those symbols. I guess you will have to load another font or symbol package for this.

Comment: @sk001, I wouldn't recommend using `fc` with `garamondx` because it's made to look like Computer Modern, not Garamond. I would find a Unicode font that has all the symbols you want and load it with `fontspec` using XeLaTeX, as @LaRiFaRi suggests. However, you don't need to use `\symbol{}`, which is really cumbersome -- you can just enter the symbol directly if it's on your keyboard. If it's not, you can use a [keyboard overlay](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222159/42880) or copy and paste.