# How to use IPA symbols in pst-asr package?

Tags: fonts, linguistics, tipa, pst-asr

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-asr,graphicx}\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts} 

\begin{document}

\asr pem \endasr

\end{document}
```

Hi, there

How can I use IPA symbols between `\asr \endasr`?
For example from the upper code, I'd like to make it \asr **pɛɱ** \endasr.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply load the package `tipa` which defines IPA symbols and use them as in

```
\asr p{\textepsilon}{\textltailm} \endasr
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-asr,graphicx}\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}

\asr p{\textepsilon}{\textltailm} \endasr

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @mangotango You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can just type them directly using a [Unicode IPA keyboard layout](http://scripts.sil.org/uniipakeyboard) or paste from an online IPA picker (see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89618/accessing-ipa-characters-when-using-charis-sil/222159#222159) to [Accessing IPA characters when using Charis SIL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89618/42880) for discussion of these options). Use `fontspec` to declare a Unicode font that has the characters you need, and then run the file with XeLaTeX instead of LaTeX. See [Typesetting phonetic symbols: Unicode or tipa?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224164/42880) for a list of reasons to use Unicode instead of `tipa`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-xkey}
\usepackage{pst-asr}
\psset{everyasr=\tiershortcuts}
\usepackage{fontspec} % you need this to be able to use a system font in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\setmainfont{Charis SIL} % you can load any font you have on your system

\begin{document}

\asr pɛɱ \endasr % no extra markup needed for the IPA characters

\end{document}
```

[image]