# Combining macron-grave diacritic

Tags: fonts

I would like to use a specific diacritic: The combining macron-grave. The USV code is `U+1DC6`, and an example of the diacritic is shown below:

[image]

I've searched through all the symbol guides I can find, but to no avail. The `tipa` package has `\textgravemid{}`, which is the right idea, but the grave and the macron are the opposite way round to what I need.

Does anyone know of a symbol like it? Or of a way of combining the macron and the grave so that they're not stacked, but one following the other? Or, failing that, whether I can define a new symbol?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should tell us a bit about the usage of this symbol. Which language is it used in? What is the context (math, text), are you using PDFLaTeX or Xe- LuaLaTeX? It would be perfect if you include an MWE which shows a minimal version of your document if you define some languages, fonts or alike.

Answer (score 8):

Using lualatex or xelatex you can use the `\accent` primitive (giving the accent before the base) or simply use the unicode combining character mechanisms referring to the character using `^^^^` or just typing directly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}

\accent"1DC6 u

u^^^^1dc6

u᷆
\end{document}
```

The last line there is

```
  U+0075 LATIN SMALL LETTER U
  U+1dc6 COMBINING MACRON-GRAVE
```

Comment: +1. @Laura, in order to type this directly, you can use an [IPA keyboard layout](http://scripts.sil.org/uniipakeyboard). See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222159/42880) for more info. In the MSKLC layout for Windows, you would type `u`, then `@`, then `8` to get `u᷆`, and the layouts for other platforms have similar shortcuts.

Answer (score 4):

Make your own.  The dimensions may need changing based on the font being used.  The `[-1ex]` controls the overset gap, the `\kern-.27ex` controls the relative horizontal placement of the two overset glyphs, while the `{-.94ex}` controls the relative vertical placement of the two overset glyphs.  Using the scalable `ex` rather than `pt` allows the macro to work at different font scales.

By setting `\useanchorwidth` to the `{T}`rue  setting, the width of the overset does not affect the spacing of the base letters (shown in the MWE on a narrow `i` to demonstrate).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{arlticle}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\mg[1]{\def\useanchorwidth{T}%
  \stackon[-1ex]{#1}{-\kern-.27ex\raisebox{-.94ex}{\`{}}}}
\begin{document}
\mg x \mg X

\Huge \mg x \mg X

Small w\mg idth
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly - thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

That diacritic seems to be used in some of the ›Bantu‹ languages: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/U%E1%B7%86.

The following works fine for me (using LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\accent\string"1DC6 u
\end{document}
```

You may want to have a look at the `newunicodechar` package. It may help you be able to type `u᷆` directly:

```
\newunicodechar{u᷆}{\accent\string"1DC6 u}
```