# LuaTeX + Roboto + \= : working with A but not with B, nor C

Tags: luatex, accents

I want to use the 'bar' accent (`\={<letter>}`) on capital letters in my document that is typesetted with `roboto`. If I compile the document using LaTeX, it works perfectly. But if I compile it using LuaLaTeX, `\={A}` is working great, but neither `\={B}` nor `\={C}`:

[image]  [image]

**Questions:** Why? How to use the 'bar'-accent with roboto and LuaLaTeX?

*Note:* I've not encounter such problem with other fonts.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
    \usepackage{ifluatex}
        \ifluatex
            \newcommand{\engine}{LuaTeX}
        \else
            \newcommand{\engine}{TeX}
        \fi
\begin{document}
    \engine: 
    \={A}
    \={B}
    \={C}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Missing character: There is no ̄ (U+0304) in font [Roboto-Regular.ttf]`

Comment: Roboto doesn't have the accent needed to build the B and C with a macron: in the log-file you get  Missing character: There is no ̄ (U+0304) in font [Roboto-Regular.ttf]. (A with macron is a real glyph, U+100).

Comment: As I wrote: A with macron is a real glyph with a unicode position and it is in the font. But B with macron must be build and while the one component (the B) is in the font, the other (the accent) is missing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I misunderstood your first comment, my bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Roboto fonts miss the U+0304 COMBINING MACRON character, and indeed you get the dreaded message

```
Missing character: There is no ̄ (U+0304) in font [Roboto-Regular.ttf]
```

You can fix this by declaring that the combinations with `\=` are dealt with in the traditional way, via `\accent`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\DeclareUnicodeEncoding{roboto}{%
  \input{tuenc.def}%
  \DeclareTextAccent{\=}{roboto}{"00AF}%
}
\makeatother

\setmainfont{Roboto}[
  Extension      = .ttf,
  NFSSEncoding   = roboto,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-RegularItalic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic,
]

\begin{document}
    \={A}
    \={B}
    \={C}
\end{document}
```

I don't see an easy way to use the package, because it doesn't allow for adding the `NFSSEncoding` option to the font choices.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The following workaround (inspired from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233378/112503) seems to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Roboto}[%
    Extension = .ttf ,
    Path = C:/path-to-font-file/ ,
    UprightFont = {Roboto-Regular},
]

\begin{document}
\=A (\accent"02C9 A)

\accent"02C9 B

\accent"02C9 C
\end{document}
```

[image]