# Fonts are not rendering correctly

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex, polyglossia

I am using xelatex for printing Malayalam fonts. This is code and it is not printing properly. In the code it is right form and in the image that produced by the code is wrong[image]

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily\Mal{Meera}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
    Case         & Marker                 & UF & SF & Gloss \\
    \hline
    Nominative   &  & ~  & ~ & \\
    Accusative   & -e \Mal{എ }\normalfont & \Mal{ആനയെ }\normalfont  & ~ & \\
    Dative       &   \Mal{ക്ക് }\normalfont                  & ~  & ~ & \\
    Instrumental &   \Mal{ആൽ  }\normalfont                & ~  & ~ & \\
    Locative     &  \Mal{ഇൽ }\normalfont             & ~  & ~ & \\
    Genitive     &  \Mal{ഉടെ, 
ഇന്റെ }\normalfont                    & ~  & ~ & \\
    Sociative    &  \Mal{ഓട് }\normalfont            & ~  & ~ & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You can easily identify the difference between code and output.
Any suggestions ?

All the fonts are available here:

```
https://smc.org.in/fonts/
or


   http://www.prokerala.com/downloads/fonts.php
```

**UPDATE**

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathchars}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily{\Mal}{Meera} [features=malayalam]


\input{blocked.sty}
\input{uhead.sty}
\input{boxit.sty}
\input{icthesis.sty}

\newcommand{\ipc}{{\sf ipc}}

\newcommand{\Prob}{\bbbp}
\newcommand{\Real}{\bbbr}
\newcommand{\real}{\Real}
\newcommand{\Int}{\bbbz}
\newcommand{\Nat}{\bbbn}

\newcommand{\NN}{{\sf I\kern-0.14emN}}   % Natural numbers
\newcommand{\ZZ}{{\sf Z\kern-0.45emZ}}   % Integers
\newcommand{\QQQ}{{\sf C\kern-0.48emQ}}   % Rational numbers
\newcommand{\RR}{{\sf I\kern-0.14emR}}   % Real numbers
\newcommand{\KK}{{\cal K}}
\newcommand{\OO}{{\cal O}}
\newcommand{\AAA}{{\bf A}}
\newcommand{\HH}{{\bf H}}
\newcommand{\II}{{\bf I}}
\newcommand{\LL}{{\bf L}}
\newcommand{\PP}{{\bf P}}
\newcommand{\PPprime}{{\bf P'}}
\newcommand{\QQ}{{\bf Q}}
\newcommand{\UU}{{\bf U}}
\newcommand{\UUprime}{{\bf U'}}
\newcommand{\zzero}{{\bf 0}}
\newcommand{\ppi}{\mbox{\boldmath $\pi$}}
\newcommand{\aalph}{\mbox{\boldmath $\alpha$}}
\newcommand{\bb}{{\bf b}}
\newcommand{\ee}{{\bf e}}
\newcommand{\mmu}{\mbox{\boldmath $\mu$}}
\newcommand{\vv}{{\bf v}}
\newcommand{\xx}{{\bf x}}
\newcommand{\yy}{{\bf y}}
\newcommand{\zz}{{\bf z}}
\newcommand{\oomeg}{\mbox{\boldmath $\omega$}}
\newcommand{\res}{{\bf res}}
\newcommand{\cchi}{{\mbox{\raisebox{.4ex}{$\chi$}}}}
%\newcommand{\cchi}{{\cal X}}
%\newcommand{\cchi}{\mbox{\Large $\chi$}}

% Logical operators and symbols
\newcommand{\imply}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\bimply}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\union}{\cup}
\newcommand{\intersect}{\cap}
\newcommand{\boolor}{\vee}
\newcommand{\booland}{\wedge}
\newcommand{\boolimply}{\imply}
\newcommand{\boolbimply}{\bimply}
\newcommand{\boolnot}{\neg}
\newcommand{\boolsat}{\!\models}
\newcommand{\boolnsat}{\!\not\models}


\newcommand{\op}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\newcommand{\s}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathcal #1}}

% Properly styled differentiation and integration operators
\newcommand{\diff}[1]{\mathrm{\frac{d}{d\mathit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\diffII}[1]{\mathrm{\frac{d^2}{d\mathit{#1}^2}}}
\newcommand{\intg}[4]{\int_{#3}^{#4} #1 \, \mathrm{d}#2}
\newcommand{\intgd}[4]{\int\!\!\!\!\int_{#4} #1 \, \mathrm{d}#2 \, \mathrm{d}#3}

% Large () brackets on different lines of an eqnarray environment
\newcommand{\Leftbrace}[1]{\left(\raisebox{0mm}[#1][#1]{}\right.}
\newcommand{\Rightbrace}[1]{\left.\raisebox{0mm}[#1][#1]{}\right)}

% Funky symobols for footnotes
\newcommand{\symbolfootnote}{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}
% now add \symbolfootnote to the beginning of the document...

\newcommand{\normallinespacing}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} \normalsize}
\newcommand{\mediumlinespacing}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} \normalsize}
\newcommand{\narrowlinespacing}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0} \normalsize}
\newcommand{\bump}{\noalign{\vspace*{\doublerulesep}}}
\newcommand{\cell}{\multicolumn{1}{}{}}
\newcommand{\spann}{\mbox{span}}
\newcommand{\diagg}{\mbox{diag}}
\newcommand{\modd}{\mbox{mod}}
\newcommand{\minn}{\mbox{min}}
\newcommand{\andd}{\mbox{and}}
\newcommand{\forr}{\mbox{for}}
\newcommand{\EE}{\mbox{E}}

\newcommand{\deff}{\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}}
\newcommand{\syncc}{~\stackrel{\textstyle \rhd\kern-0.57em\lhd}{\scriptstyle L}~}

\def\coop{\mbox{\large $\rhd\!\!\!\lhd$}}
\newcommand{\sync}[1]{\raisebox{-1.0ex}{$\;\stackrel{\coop}{\scriptscriptstyle
#1}\,$}}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\newcommand{\Figref}[1]{Figure~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\fig}[3]{
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
 \begin{center}
 \scalebox{#3}{\includegraphics{figs/#1.ps}}
 \vspace{-0.1in}
 \caption[ ]{\label{#1} #2}
 \end{center}
 \end{figure}
}

\newcommand{\figtwo}[8]{
 \begin{figure}
 \parbox[b]{#4 \textwidth}{
 \begin{center}
 \scalebox{#3}{\includegraphics{figs/#1.ps}}
 \vspace{-0.1in}
 \caption{\label{#1}#2}
 \end{center}
 }
 \hfill
 \parbox[b]{#8 \textwidth}{
 \begin{center}
 \scalebox{#7}{\includegraphics{figs/#5.ps}}
 \vspace{-0.1in}
 \caption{\label{#5}#6}
 \end{center}
 }
 \end{figure}

}
```

All the code in the Header

**UPDATE**
The problem caused because of older version of Texlive (2012). In Tex live 2015 there is no problem.

Comment: This is a quite bad example. Are you really still using \documentstyle? What is the "doument" environment? Also \Malfont is not defined.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  Changed to working copy

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. I need to pass font properties to \Mal.  I am writing a thesis so there are many files.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. That cannot possibly correspond to your working copy ... Does Charis SIL include the glyphs required? Why is this tagged with the pdfTeX engine if you aren't even using it? You don't seem to set any language for the document, despite loading `polyglossia`. Presumably you need at least 2 languages set up here and probably distinct font configurations for each.

Comment: Yes. I have four languages in same document

Comment: @cfr Yes. I have four languages in same document. This not a problem related to four languages in the same document where main font is Charis SIL. I need all other for  providing examples.

Comment: Your question is answered [in my answer to your other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304304/4778). I think this may be a duplicate.

Comment: @Alenanno, this is not a duplicate of that question. The OP is asking about why the Malayalam text does not come out correctly, which has nothing to do with IPA symbols.

Comment: @karu, have you checked that the font Meera has all the glyphs you need for your Malayalam text?

Comment: @JasonZentz But it has all to do with fonts and xelatex. The duplicate is not the font name, but the problem, which can be solved with the same answer in the other question.

Comment: @JasonZentz. This a very different question. It about rendering of orthography. The font I use  have all the glyph support but its rendered incorrectly.

Comment: @karu I tested the answer I gave in the other question with the information on this question and it works. So the solution is the same.

Comment: @Alenanno \Mal{ആനയെ} This one  for example. Needs to  display as it  is. Could  you please post what you got in PDF? I mean the symbols

Or This one \Mal{ക്ക് }

Comment: @karu If you disagree with the closure, you could post a question on [Meta] and explain why you think this question should stay open. I'll answer there to explain my reasoning. Comments are not very well-suited for these discussions, and on Meta we'll have more space to discuss (also other users might post there).

Comment: @Alenanno Done.  http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6600/xelatex-not-rendering-forn-correctly

Comment: @JasonZentz  The font "Meera" has support of all glyph need for the language. The is the official font  of the language for all purpose.

Comment: @karu: I won't discuss if it is a duplicate or not. But it is still a badly phrased question. The code has no \documentclass command, it uses "doument" instead of "document", the \end{document} is missing. You obviously didn't try the code yourself. So why should I bother and test it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is header I have usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathchars}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily{\Mal}{Rachana} [features=malayalam]


\input{blocked.sty}
\input{uhead.sty}
\input{boxit.sty}
\input{icthesis.sty}

Comment: This this comment improve your question? All the \input commands are faulty, and also quite probably irrelevant. Beside this: Don't post code in comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. I have a lot code as the part of the thesis header. I reduced the version so that people can understand it. Any way I am posting all the code in the header

Comment: But you reduced the code too much. As it is it can not be compiled. Try it out. Copy and paste your example above in some empty test document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I hope you  haven´t got the font

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. It compile here

Comment: It compiles now -- after you corrected all the errors. But I can't test it, I don't have the font and as I don't read the script can't download it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. You need to download  it from here: https://wiki.smc.org.in/Fonts. Please press Meera Download

Comment: @UlrikeFischer or You could download it  from here http://www.prokerala.com/downloads/fonts.php

Comment: Looks ok for me in a current texlive 2015. Don't load the inputenc package, it is useless for xelatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am using texlive 2012 may be that is the problem

Comment: @karu Oh, try updating then! See if that fixes it.