# Insert barless f (ſ) into document?

Tags: latin-modern

I am looking to use the barless f as shown in the title, but the only option seems to be this (ſ) which still retains half of the bar. Are there any solutions to this or relevant packages that I can use?

Many thanks

Comment: I think this is a "long s" (U+017F). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538196/how-can-i-produce-the-old-glyph-long-s-in-latex

Comment: as @mbert says, that is an s not an f, see https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?Insert%20barless%20f%20(%C5%BF)%20into%20document?

Comment: [fonts - Bar-less “f” and finetuning existing characters - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88992/bar-less-f-and-finetuning-existing-characters) perhaps. But depends on what's the semantic meaning of your desired character solution may vary.

Comment: Welcome. // Just being curious: in which context or for which purpose will you use it?

Answer (score 1):

What's a “barless f”?

You perhaps mean the “long s”, which is Unicode U+017F. Some fonts have no ornament, some fonts have a small dent.

[image]

It's a choice of the font designer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Typo fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unicode has

`U+0283` ʃ  LATIN SMALL LETTER ESH
`U+AB4D` ꭍ  lATIN SMALL LETTER BASELINE ESH
`U+017F` ſ LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S

If the font you are using has the characters they can be used without any special markup. For example the Windows Times New Roman, with lualatex

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
U+0283 ʃ  LATIN SMALL LETTER ESH  

U+AB4D ꭍ  LATIN SMALL LETTER BASELINE ESH  

U+017F ſ LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S
\end{document}
```